# error while Installing the ubuntu OS

Tags: system-installation, architecture, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on the virtual box on my HP laptop it has following configurations:

6Gb RAM
i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz
64-bit Operating System

But while it installs the OS it shows me error, which states that:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor doesn't support 64bit operating systems.
Download the [32bit Ubuntu installation image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso)